# Add multiple inputs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a form with two inputs where, when the user selects a **description** from the **datalist** the second input is filled with the **product**. It works fine -> [bootbly1](http://www.bootply.com/KAIwvoZJMF)

Now I want to add dynamically inputs in the form. The inputs are inserted fine but the above function doesn't apply to the new inputs..

Here is the final [bootbly](http://www.bootply.com/mN7RQPtTpA)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
            <form id="bookForm" action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input class="form-control" name="description-0" id="ajax" list="json-datalist" placeholder="Description" type="text">
                    <datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 160px;">
                    <input class="form-control" name="product-0" placeholder="product" type="text">
                </div>
                
                 <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>   
           
            <!-- The template for adding new field -->
            <div class="form-group hide" id="bookTemplate">
                 <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input class="form-control" name="description" id="ajax" list="json-datalist" placeholder="description" type="text">
                    <datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 160px;">
                    <input class="form-control" name="product" placeholder="product" type="text">
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
var counter = 0;    
var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');
    
    var jsonOptions = [{
                        "product": "11111",
                        "description": "description 1"
                      }, {
                        "product": "22222",
                        "description": "description 2"
                      }, {
                        "product": "33333",
                        "description": "description 3"
                      }, {
                        "product": "44444",
                        "description": "description 4"
                      }, {
                        "product": "55555",
                        "description": "description 5"
                      }]; 

    jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
                    
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      
      option.value = item.description;
      option.text = item.description;
      option.setAttribute('data-product', item.product);
      dataList.appendChild(option);
    });

$(function() {
    $('#ajax').change(function() {
        var description = $(this).val();
        var product = $('#json-datalist > option[value="' + description + '"]').data('product');
        $('input[name=product-'+ counter + ']').val(product);
        
    });
});

    
$('#bookForm')
    // Add button click handler
    .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
        counter++;
        var $template = $('#bookTemplate'),
            $clone    = $template
                            .clone()
                            .removeClass('hide')
                            .removeAttr('id')
                            .attr('data-book-index', counter)
                            .insertBefore($template);

        // Update the name attributes
        $clone
            .find('[name="description"]').attr('name', 'description-' + counter).end()
            .find('[name="product"]').attr('name', 'product-' + counter).end();
    })

    // Remove button click handler
    .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
        var $row  = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
            index = $row.attr('data-book-index');

        // Remove element containing the fields
        $row.remove();
    });
```

One more thing is that if the user presses some times the plus button to create inputs and then tries to fill the first one, then the last input will be filled..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: or also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id `json-datalist`.

Comment: The problem is in your counter

Comment: The problem is in `$('#ajax')` as all your created inputs has the same id. Modify your selector and it will work

Comment: @Legionar I am new to javasctipt.. can you help as I am new to JS

Comment: I try to alter the `#ajax` so the new created ones have a different name, but no success till now.. any suggestion? @Valijon

Comment: Not elegant, but works: [http://www.bootply.com/ZckX8mlKOQ](http://www.bootply.com/ZckX8mlKOQ)

Comment: Post it as an answer to take the credits !!!! @Valijon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your selector for dynamic descriptions ("#ajax") and counter (taking the last modified counter) to update product were wrong.

Solution: http://www.bootply.com/ZckX8mlKOQ